# Rails using a variable on left side of where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am looking to do the following:

```
var = 'bank_id'
id = '100'

Bank.where(var: id) or
Bank.where("? = ?", var, id)
```

Bank is a model.
bank_id is an attribute of the model 
and it is taking it as a string.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Are you sure that the name of the column is 'bank_id'? Or is it just 'id'

Comment: Bank is not the actual table. Its a table which has bank_id as a foreign key. Just to make it easy to understand, I put it that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where does accept a hash witch gets mapped to the correct SQL WHERE.

```
Bank.where(var: id)
```

is actually

```
Bank.where({:var => id})
```

So you can construct your own hash key:

```
Bank.where({ var.to_s => id })
```

Or shorter:

```
Bank.where(var => id)
```

Just to clarify:
The difference actually lies in the different syntax for hash. There are basically two versions.

1. The old "Hash-Rocket" syntax { key => value } actually accepts anything as key.
2. The new JSON style always uses symbols als keys and thus var does not get interpreted as a variable but as the symbol :var.

[Always coding](http://alwayscoding.ca/momentos/2012/06/15/ruby-hash-syntax-hashrocket-vs-json-style/) has a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

There's also a Arel Table approach:

```
Bank.where(Bank.arel_table[var].eq(id))
```

Answer (score 0):

That's possible:

```
var = 'bank_id'
id = '100'

Bank.where("#{var} = ?", id)
```

But what are you using it for? Maybe there's a better way to solve the 'real' problem here.

Comment: I absolutely agree with @JanDintel! There should be a better way of solving the 'real' problem!

Comment: I am iterating through a list of models and looking for matching primary key ids.

Comment: I don't know the exact problem, but why don't you use associations?